# Lightbox via API

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma *Lightbox* funcionando perfeitamente bem, usando:

```
<!-- INICIO FORMULARIO BOTAO PAGSEGURO -->
<form action="https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/checkout/v2/cart.html?action=add" method="post" onsubmit="PagSeguroLightbox(this,
    {
         success : function(transactionCode)
         {
            user_transactionCode_save(1, 2, transactionCode);
            alert('<b>Seu código de transação é:</b> ' + transactionCode);
         },
         abort : function() {
            document.write('<b>Você não concluiu a sua compra</b>');
         }
    }); return false;"
>

<!-- NÃO EDITE OS COMANDOS DAS LINHAS ABAIXO -->
<input type="hidden" name="itemCode" value="*****************" />
<input type="image" src="https://p.simg.uol.com.br/out/pagseguro/i/botoes/pagamentos/209x48-comprar-assina.gif" name="submit" alt="Pague com PagSeguro - Ã© rÃ¡pido, grÃ¡tis e seguro!" />
</form>
<!-- FINAL FORMULARIO BOTAO PAGSEGURO -->
```

É bem simples, mas, o retorno do transactionCode está sendo sempre 1.

O que há?

Comment: Onde está a ser declarada `checkoutCode`? e qual é o seu valor no momento de chamar o `PagSeguroLightbox`? Falta-te um `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Opa, declarando-a: `var checkoutCode=...` ocorre o mesmo, ao adicionar o `e.preventDefault();` também

Comment: Como conseguiu resolver essa situação ? estou tentando o mesmo.